# Laravel queue daemon using DB processor constantly (supervisord)

Tags: mysql, laravel, queue, amazon-rds

I'm running our Laravel queue daemon with the following configuration (low volume email jobs essentially), but I've noticed a constant CPU usage on our Amazon RDS server dependent on how many queue processes are running. Each contributes to 4.3% ***constant*** CPU usage on the RDS instance. So we've been sitting on 9% CPU non-stop for the last several weeks.

The queue is mostly empty, only occasionally having a few email jobs to issue, but the queue worker is *constantly* throwing work at the database! When the number of processes is 1, it goes down to 4.3% constant so it's definitely the queue worker.

Anyone had this issue?

```
[program:example-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/example.com.au/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/root/queue.log
```

[image: Amazon RDS CPU usage graph]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not an issue, it is how it works with the combination of multiple processes (in your case supervisor). Laravel's database queue driver constantly(excluding 3 seconds sleep in your case) keeps querying(`select`) on your server to get available job(s). If you replace it with `redis` then the same processes will constantly query on redis server executing sorted set(`zrangebyscore`, `zremrangebyscore`) and list(`lpop`) commands to query the queue.

The following method is from DatabaseQueue.

```
protected function getNextAvailableJob($queue)
{
    $job = $this->database->table($this->table)
                ->lockForUpdate()
                ->where('queue', $this->getQueue($queue))
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $this->isAvailable($query);
                    $this->isReservedButExpired($query);
                })
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->first();

    return $job ? new DatabaseJobRecord((object) $job) : null;
}
```

since you say "having a few email jobs to issue",

You may;

- increase `--sleep`
- decrease number of processes
- run your queue:work command without supervisor such as binding to `minutely cron`.
- switch to redis queue driver(it won't create an overhead on your database), AWS ElastiCache `cache.t2.micro` would be more than enough and you won't pay anything(for a year) because it is in free tier for 12 months.